# How to Use CollectEntries in Groovy to create a map that has multiple values for each key

Tags: java, groovy, collections, hashmap

I have the following List of Lists. It is in the format of [String, Double]

```
def data = [ ['A', 15.2], ['A', 14.7], ['B', 6.54], ['A', 4.5], ['A', 16.8], ['A', 7.7], ['C', 1.5], ['B', 13.1], ['B', 6], ['C', 10.1] ]
```

I want to have a map where I group each sector(String) as a key with multiple associated temperatures(double)

I was able to already get my desired output just by iterating through the data with .each

```
Map<String, List<BigDecimal>> groupedData = new HashMap<>()
data.each {it ->
    String sector = it[0]
    BigDecimal temp = it[1]

    if(!groupedData.containsKey(sector))
    {
        groupedData.put(sector, [])
    }
    groupedData.get(sector).add(temp)

}
```

I am new to groovy and have been trying to figure out if it is possible to get the same output using only collectentries. I know groovy doesnt require explicit variable declarations but please include them in your explanation so i can fully understand what is happening in the code

Answer (score 1):

2 options. both give the same result

```
def data = [ ['A', 15.2], ['A', 14.7], ['B', 6.54], ['A', 4.5], ['A', 16.8], 
             ['A', 7.7], ['C', 1.5], ['B', 13.1], ['B', 6], ['C', 10.1] ]

println data.groupBy{it[0]}.collectEntries{k,v-> [ k,v.collect{it[1]} ]}
println data.groupBy{it[0]}.collectEntries{k,v-> [ k,v*.get(1)] }
```

Comment: Would this be more efficient than the way I initially had it? Just curious because of all the nested closures

Comment: @snbmt21 The closures are not the inefficient part, Building up the intermediate result is -- if you happen to work with _lots of_ tuples. And even if you are not interested in the same shape of the result and just go with `groupBy` it's very likely, that it's implemented like your code. You will always pay a price for using Groovy and you will for writing a wonderfully declarative one-liner, that tells you at a glance (if you know the verbs), what is happening.  But it's very unlikely, that it will beat imperative "Java" code (like yours) on the JVM on a regular basis.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Can use inject as well: `data.inject([:].withDefault { [] }){ m, a -> m[a[0]] << a[1]; m }`